# Rails: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: prize, optininpartner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting this error, and I have made the attributes accesible in the model:

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible  :optinpartners_attributes, :prizes_attributes, :css, :description,      :enddate, :promotion, :rules, :slug, :startdate, :title


 accepts_nested_attributes_for :optinpartners
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :prizes


  has_many :contest_entries
  has_many :contestants, :through => :contest_entries


  has_many :contest_prizes
  has_many :prizes, :through => :contest_prizes  

  has_many :contest_optins
  has_many :optinpartners, :through => :contest_optins
```

the exact error is:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: prize, optininpartner


app/controllers/contests_controller.rb:49:in `new'
app/controllers/contests_controller.rb:49:in `create'
```

As per my understanding: if the attribute is made accesible in the model this should not be a problem. But mass assignment is also a security vulnerability, so how do I fix this without sacrificing security?

**EDIT:**
As Requested: this is the _form.erb.html file for Contest. and This snippet is for the Prizes and Opt-Ins

```
<h2> Enter information on prizes </h2>

<%= f.fields_for :prize do |builder| %>

<%= builder.label :prize, "Prize" %><br/>
 <%= builder.text_field :prize%><br/>
<br/>
<%= builder.label :description, "Description" %>
<%= builder.text_field :description%>


<%end%>
<hr>

<hr>
<h2> Enter information on Opt-In Partners </h2>

<%= f.fields_for :optinpartner do |builder| %>

<%= builder.label :name, "Name of Partner" %> 
<%= builder.text_field :name%>

<%end%>
<hr>
```

Comment: you have made the attributes_accessible, but not the actual object if you do `attr_accessible  :optinpartners` it should work as expected.

Comment: Can you post the view form code that is being passed to the `create` action?

Comment: add `:prize` and `:optininpartner` to `attr_accessible`.

Comment: @AlexLynham: `:prize` and `:optinpartner` should not have been passed to the `ContestsController` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the plural :optinpartners_attributes, :prizes_attributes in attr_accessible, use the singular form - :optionpartner_attributes and :prize_attributes.

```
attr_accessible  :optinpartner_attributes, :prize_attributes, :css, :description,      :enddate, :promotion, :rules, :slug, :startdate, :title
```

Comment: i still get this error:
    `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: prize, optinpartner`